# Create boot media (CD-ROM or USB) to boot to a completely white screen

Tags: bootable-media

I am going to take my laptop for repair because of screen issues. When the screen is displaying a fair color, I see some light dots appear.

Because of sensitive data, I am not including my harddrive.

Can anyone suggest a way to make the system bootup to a white screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messy and I'm sure there is a better way, but a live CD with some linux flavor on it (change background to white).